# How to use AlarmManager using PendingIntent.activity() or PendingIntent.getBroadcast?

Tags: android, synchronization, alarmmanager

I read many tutorials but got no solution. I want to use AlarmManager for synchronization purpose. I want when I select "after15Minutes" checkbox alarm set with current time in system (how to save that particular time in database. Is it important to save time in database?) and Refresh list in every 15 minutes. I don't know how to bind checkBoxes value with alarm and how to make it possible. totally stuck.

My code:

```
  private final class syncOkClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {   //Implement search method here
        if(after15mint.isChecked())
        {
            // Some code!!! or Alarm Manager !!!
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "15 Minute checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver Activity:

```
 public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent syncIntent = new Intent(context, BroadCastReceiver.class);
    syncIntent.putExtra("sync", 0);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, syncIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*20, pIntent);
}
public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadCastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

}

Any Suggestion will be helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your alarm in your onClick code:

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{   //Implement search method here
    if(after15mint.isChecked())
    {
        // Create alarm intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadCastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Schedule alarm.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

There is no requirement for you to save the alarm time in your own database.

Concerning the many tutorials you read that didn't help, a good place to start is the Android SDK's ApiDemos, where you will find working code in ApiDemos/App/Alarm/AlarmController that implements one shot alarms as well as repeating alarms.